# PHP session variable cannot be read in other page

Tags: php, session

I am building a login page using php.
I don't know why the session variable does not work.

Here is my login.php

```
<?php
function loginFail()
{
    echo "<script> alert(\"Invalid user name or password\");";
    echo "location.href=\"index.php\";";
    echo "</script>";
}
if (empty($_POST["loginName"])|| empty($_POST["adminPwd"])) {
    loginFail();
} else {
    $userName=$_POST["loginName"];
    $password=$_POST["adminPwd"];

    if (($userName=="user") && ($password=="password")) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["isLogined"]="Ok";
        header("location:admin.php");
    } else {
        loginFail();
    }
}
?>
```

Here is admin.php

```
<?php
 include 'checkSession.php';
?>
```

This is checkSession.php source code

```
<?php
function loginFail()
{
    echo "<script> alert(\"Session Expired, please login again\");";
    echo "location.href=\"index.php\";";
    echo "</script>";
}
echo $_SESSION["isLogined"];    
?>
```

The output of checkSession.php is :

Undefined variable: _SESSION

I have tried replace

```
header("location:admin.php");
```

with

```
echo "<script>";
echo "location.href=\"admin.php\";";
echo "</script>";
```

However, it still does not work.

Furthermore, I have tried replace :

```
header("location:admin.php");
```

With

```
echo $_SESSION["isLogined"];
```

It can display the word "Ok".
Would you tell me how to fix the problem?

Comment: Do you make sure that `session_start()` is always present in your pages?

Comment: `admin.php` is missing `session_start()`.

Comment: The problem is you haven't start the session like session_start() in every page you need to write this function in every page only then you can use the session global variable

Comment: Because of checksession.php will be included every page that required to check session, so can I add the session_start() in the checksession.php only?